# Div overflow not hidden properly

Tags: css, html, overflow

I'm working on this site - [link removed]

It works in everything other than IE7 and IE8 in compatibility mode (don't care about IE6), where the vacancies lists on the right aren't hidden correctly by their parent overflow property.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get to the bottom of this, its driving me up the wall, anyone got any ideas whatsoever?

Below is an image of the issue, chrome on the left, IE8 compat mode on the right.

Cheers, -Ben

[screenshot removed]

Comment: Why do do care about compatibility mode? Your site has IE7/8 in standards mode and unless the user manually activates it, then everything is fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure it out so I'm just doing a javascript workaround.

Thanks anyway guys

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firebug's inspect element on your list, the div with classes "rssWrapper rss1" have these styles: "overflow: visible; height: auto; width: 248px; padding-right: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;"

You probably should also specify a height for this one(even just for IE7/8) since it is the one that overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Your XHTML isn't sent as application/xhtml+xml. Either send it as the correct MIME or get HTML 5.